# XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24

Tags: java, java-11

I am facing issue after upgrading java version to 11 from 8 with some library files.

I have tried to check the xmlbean version and found it is xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate SchemaTypeSystemImpl (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException): is the version of xbean.jar correct?
        at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sBB5A8E63226683B652C1BA5AF3C921F5.TypeSystemHolder.loadTypeSystem(Unknown Source)
        at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sBB5A8E63226683B652C1BA5AF3C921F5.TypeSystemHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sBB5A8E63226683B652C1BA5AF3C921F5.index) - code 3
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:1522)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.initFromHeader(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:260)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:183)
        ... 66 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found by myself. There were two xmlbeans jar files related to with different version. I have removed the older version and it worked.

Comment: how to find these 2 jars ?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying older version of `xmlbeans` plugin fixes the problem. i.e. used 2.2.0 version instead of 2.3.3. with JDK 11.